# Fundamental group of formal punctured disc and punctured affine line

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-covers

On a course that ended some time ago, I was handed the following problem:

> **Problem:** Compute $\pi_1^{ét} (\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb C} \setminus \{ 0 \}, \overline x)$.
>
> **Hint:** Find all finite algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{C}((t))$.

It's easy to compute the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{C}((t))$. Also, I know there are at least two different ways to compute $\pi_1^{ét} (\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb C} \setminus \{ 0 \})$:

- by using the comparison with the profinite completion of the topological fundamental group,
- by using Hurwitz formula (cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/42656/403625)).

However, I wonder, if it is possible to formally finish this proof using the above hint.

> **Question:** is it possible to show directly that $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ and $\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec} \Spec \mathbb{C}((t))$ have the same étale fundamental group?

The intuition is clear: $\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec} \Spec \mathbb{C}((t)) = \Spec \mathbb C[[t]] \setminus \{ (t) \}$ is a "formal" punctured disc and thus should "morally" have the same homotopy type as $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$. But is it possible to formalize this intuition (possibly even using some higher machinery from étale homotopy theory)? Does it generalize to higher dimensions?

It seems to me that the answer would be quite informative, not only for this problem.

I am asking this question here, since a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/42656/403625) posted on Stack Exchange did not get any satisfactory (from my point view) answer.

Comment: +1, especially for the subquestion "Does it generalize to higher dimensions?", which I interpret as asking about the etale homotopy type of $\mathbb{A}^n \setminus \{0\}$ versus its formal completion near zero.

Comment: I'm not an algebraic geometer. I *think* the hint was intended as: an etale cover of $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{0\}$ restricts to an etale cover of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}((t))) = \mathbb{D}^1 \setminus \{0\}$; now classify those, and show that each one extends uniquely to $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{0\}$. But this is a disappointing interpretation: as you point out, it is more satisfying to have a general criterion that says that the inclusion $\mathbb{D}^k \setminus\{0\} \subset \mathbb{A}^k \setminus\{0\}$ is an etale homotopy equivalence.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd: I thought of using the hint the way you suggested, but it doesn't seem obvious that the covers of the punctered disc extend **uniquely**. Besides, exactly as you mentioned, I would be more satisfied with the "étale homotopy type" statement.

Comment: Minor comment, we have an equiv of etale ho-types  from an n-disc to affine n-space. We'd like to "remove a point". The result is that *in this case* this is valid, it certainly isn't in general, it'd be nice to know when this sort of reasoning can be applied.

Comment: Have you tried asking the person who handed you the problem?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg I will definitely ask the person, as soon as I will get touch with him. But I'm afraid that he meant a hand-waving argument rather then something formal.

Comment: If you know that $\mathbb A^1$ and the formal disk are simply connected (requiring characteristic 0), then van Kampen should tell you that the Galois group of the formal disk surjects to the Galois group of $\mathbb A^1$.